# Typescript make one parameter type depend on the other parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have

```
interface Action<T> {
    assignAction(key: keyof T, value: any): void;
}
```

Say `T` is of type

```
{
    users: User[];
    accounts: Account[];
}
```

Now, when calling `assignAction`, let's say I want to pass `users`. So this action is false because types don't match:

```
assignAction('users', accounts)
```

I don't know how to validate `value`, since its type depends on what you choose for `key`.

Comment: `createAction`  should be `assignAction`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to add a generic to the `assignAction` function to help describe this relationship.

```
interface Action<T> {
    assignAction<K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]): void;
}
```

Then once your `Action` instance is given a generic type it knows how to associate the relationship between key and value when you call `assignAction`

Comment: Followup: don't think you will have to manually type the function generic each time. It infers the generic from the parameters. No need to type it out manually. Feel free to try pasting this into the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and you should see that you can simply type `assignAction('users', ` and intellisense should show you that it understand that the only accepted type for the second parameter is type `User[]`.

Comment: Hello @casieber! Your answer is great. I have the following question - is there a way to work with the `value` like access its properties etc.? I tried to do it with a switch on the `key` but it didn't work since the type of `value` is a union of all T[K] types. Any help would be great, thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
interface TypeA {
    objectIdA: string
}

interface TypeB {
    objectIdB: string
}

interface TypeC {
    objectIdC: string
}

enum Param1 {
    TypeA = "TypeA",
    TypeBC = "TypeBC"
}



type INamespaceKeyMap =
    & Record<Param1.TypeA, TypeA>
    & Record<Param1.TypeBC, TypeB | TypeC>;

type INamespaceKeys<T extends Param1.TypeA | Param1.TypeBC> = INamespaceKeyMap[T];

function test<NS extends Param1, Key extends INamespaceKeys<NS>>(namespace: NS, key: Key) {
    console.log("Called");
}

const objectA = {
    objectIdA: "test"
} as TypeA;

const objectB = {
    objectIdB: "test"
} as TypeB;

const objectC = {
    objectIdC: "test"
} as TypeC;

test(Param1.TypeA, objectB) // not allowed
test(Param1.TypeA, objectA)
test(Param1.TypeBC, objectA) // not allowed
test(Param1.TypeBC, objectB)
test(Param1.TypeBC, objectC)
```